# Firefox process network activity

Tags: windows-7

I am confused about firefox process network activity when i start my firefox browser.  This is the screenshot i took right after I started my browser with google set as my homepage.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled within Firefox? To be honest it just looks like a trace route.

Comment: I have some extension enables but I am puzzled by cache.googlevideo.com

Comment: Well cache.googlevideo.com is Youtube related. Perhaps you have some extension relating to Youtube.com

Comment: @ST34M yes it was extensions/addons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose what this is - try:

- Does it happen with another browser?  This will confirm that it is definitely on firefox oad and not some other application in youy system tray etc... with the same name as firefox.  I know this sounds stupid, but I've seen it before where a user renamed utorrent.exe to firefox.exe on their works computer to try and hide it from me.
- What happens if you change your homepage to Yahoo or somehwere else temporarily?  If they disappear, it's your homepage - if they don't - its probably an addon.
- If we are pretty sure it is an addon - try restarting Firefox without Addons: (See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) (`Menu` > `Help` > `Restart with addons disabled`)

Looking at the list of entries in your perfmon screenshot - I would guess its something youtube related.  Google bought Youtube a while back so the cache.googlevideo.com entry would point to Youtube.